# The gray "margin" when Plot3D with a RegionFunction

Tags: plotting

The following command

```
Plot3D[{(x^2 + y^2)^0.5, -(x^2 + y^2)^0.5}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Mesh -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> LightPink, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", LightPink}}]
```

produces

> [image]

How do I remove the gray "margins" at $z=2,-2$ in the plot? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add [`ClippingStyle -> None`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClippingStyle.html)

```
Plot3D[{(x^2 + y^2)^0.5, -(x^2 + y^2)^0.5}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Mesh -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> LightPink, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", LightPink}}, 
 ClippingStyle -> None]
```

[image]